# How do I create and use a functionpointer with alternativ parameterlist in c++ class

Tags: c++, function-pointers

back with another function pointer question ;)

I want to create a function pointer in my class that can point to different functions with have different parameterlists. That is I want a functionpointer that can point to and call all of the below functions (with its resp parameters).

funct1 takes a function pointer and

calls func2 with a pointer to func3,

func2 calls func3

In the C-code they are declared as:

```
typedef int         (*FUNCTION)();

int  func1(long sec, FUNCTION func, int argc, long *argv);
int  func2(FUNCTION func);
int  func3();
```

and called like this

```
func1(b->argv[0], func2, 3, arglist){ func(func3); }
```

Now I have created a class cDP5 to hold those methods and the function pointer
I've declared like this

```
typedef int(cDP5::*FUNCTION)(int *fc, char *buf, int sz);
```

but get compilation errors on this call

```
func1(b->argv[0], func2, 3, arglist);
```

receive this error:

```
cDP5.cpp:725:48: error: no matching function for call to ‘cDP5::func1(long&, <unresolved overloaded function type>, int, long int [3])’
cDP5.cpp:725:48: note: candidate is:
In file included from cDP5.cpp:11:0:
cDP5.h:96:9: note: int cDP5::func1(long int, cDP5::FUNCTION, int, long int*)
cDP5.h:96:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘cDP5::FUNCTION {aka int (cDP5::*)(int*, char*, int)}’
```

OK I think if I try to make a FUNCTION cast like this then

```
func1(b->argv[0], (cDP5::FUNCTION)func2, 3, arglist);
```

but then I get this error:

```
cDP5.cpp:725:45: error: cannot convert ‘cDP5::func2’ from type ‘int (cDP5::)(int, long int*)’ to type ‘cDP5::FUNCTION {aka int (cDP5::*)(int*, char*, int)}’
```

Any ideas how to create and use the wanted functionpointer inside a c++ class?
Or do I need to create one for each parameterlist?

Comment: Your 1st call in C looks somehow wrong. Btw. the 2nd parameter of `func1` takes a function pointer where the signature of `func3` is matching but the one of `func2` not. If you call `func1` with `func2` as 2nd arg. then this should cause a type mismatch error.

Comment: Hi Scheff, I fully agree with you but this works.!!?? I don't know how and since the code is from the 80-90:th it might be the reason.

Comment: Regarding the missmatch errors it's true for the C++ code since it's newer. Am I to take your comment as that the answer is, I have to make a pointer to every  situation (different parameterlists)?

Comment: About C: the C compiler is much more lax regarding type checks. K&R C nearly didn't type check anything. (Protos were even not invented.) This changed step by step with the distinct standards.

Comment: About C++: It is a real difference whether to store a function pointer or a method pointer. At best, a `static` class method can be handled by a function pointer. Most APIs (e.g. `std::function` which cover both) do this on cost of some performance. (I once digged into this topic when I was making a simple signal/slot implementation.) Clever alternatives are often platform dependent. Unfortunately, I don't have useful links at hand nor can find them by google rapidly...

Comment: Finally: C++ is very strict regarding types. To resemble your early C sample, you have to straighten your function/method types. More help would require a minimal, complete, self-standing sample.

Comment: Scheff you are most helpful as it is, though I think that I should go towards strict c++ create specifik fptr's if so for readability. The old code is without comments and hence very hard to understand or get a grip of. You mention static functions, can you elaborate it a bit?

Comment: No. You may think: `static` vs. `extern` function. (In this case, it denotes the storage class and is most important for the linker.) I mentioned [**static class methods**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static). (Search in the linked site for **Static member functions**.) I cannot find an appropriate explanation or link but from my experience I would say: static methods are extern. (The `static` is not meant/compiled as storage class.)

Answer (score 0):

OK, based on what Schiff has mentioned and my own research I've found that it is not possible to create one function pointer that take multiple paremeterlists.
I have to create functionpointer for each parameterlist.

Though there is an option to use template paramters that I found in [template function pointer parameter in a class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27423913/template-function-pointer-parameter-in-a-class-method) That I think would eas up the parameter types somewhat ;)